# 1999 Toyota RAV 4 Car Stops when AC is powered on after driving for a while

Tags: toyota, ac, hvac, rav4

While driving my 1998/99 Toyota RAV 4 car for sometime with the Ac powered on, the engine goes off.

Once i start the car, it responds and it does not stop at all when i off the AC, once AC is on , it will be offing the engine.

Please who have an idea what could me causing this on my car.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though your A/C compressor is locked up. You can test it by trying to turn the A/C compressor by hand (without the engine running, of course). Remember, there are two portions to the front of the A/C compressor where it attaches to the engine. You have the clutch portion which is contained within the pulley (where the belt rides). Then you have the compressor itself, which contains the other half of the clutch on the snout of it. You should be able to turn the hub by hand. If you cannot, I'd bet that's your issue.

Comment: i really appreciate your solution, i will check this and get respond back.